# Is it good etiquette to upvote answers to questions already marked answered?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Just curious, when I find a particular answer (not necessarily the accepted answer) to an old question which has already been answered (say one year ago), is it good etiquette to upvote it?

I ask because I've occassionally found similiar questions to what I was originally intending to ask and the posts for those questions answered my actual query.

Comment: i'm surprised you even had to ask. what gave you the impression that it might not be good etiquette?  (And to be clear, I don't mean that in a sarcastic "what gave you that impression, idiot" kind of way. I'm genuinely curious what made you think that.)

Comment: @Kip: Not sure really but I always had the idea that a question was considered closed once an answer had been accepted. So no more upvoting, comments, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is exactly what should happen.

We up vote answers that are useful to us no matter what timeframe. Even though the answer might have been written a year ago, it is still useful, and the author should be rewarded.

Comment: +1 because it's still right, 29 minutes after you wrote it.

Comment: I will upvote this answer in 6 months from now.

Comment: @Aarobot: I couldn't wait that long. I'd forget.